# How to apply MICE imputations on test set?

Tags: r, imputation, r-mice, multiple-mice

I have two separate data sets: one for `train` (1000000 observation) and the other one for `test` (1000000 observation). I divided the `train` set into 3 sets (`mytrain`: 700000 observations, `myvalid`: 150000 observations, `mytest`:150000 observations). The`test` set with 1000000 observations doesn't include the target variable, so it should be used for the final test. Since there are some missing values for categorical variables, I need to use mice to impute them. I should reuse the imputation done on `mytrain` set to fill the missing values in the `myvalid`, `mytest` and `test` sets. Based on the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33500047/r-mice-machine-learning-re-use-imputation-scheme-from-train-to-test-set), I should do this:

```
data2 <- rbind(mytrain,myval,mytest,test)
data2$ST_EMPL <- as.factor(data2$ST_EMPL)
data2$TYP_RES <- as.factor(data2$TYP_RES)

imp <-  mice(data2, method = "cart", m = 1, maxit = 1, seed = 123,
             ignore = c(rep(FALSE, 700000),rep(TRUE, 1300000)))
data2.imp <- complete(imp,1) 
summary(imp)

mytrainN <- data2.imp[1:700000,]
myvalN <- data2.imp[700001:850000,]
mytestN <- data2.imp[850001:1000000,]
testN <- data2.imp[1000001:2000000,]
```

However, since the `test` set does not have the target column, it is not possible to merge it with `mytrain`, `mytest`, and `myvalid`. Is it possible to add a hypothetical target column (with the value of say 10 for all 1000000 observations) to the `test` set?

Comment: You should remove the target column before doing imputation. It doesn't make sense to use the target for imputation, when you are trying to infer the target!

Comment: @shadowtalker Thanks a lot. As you said, target variable should be removed, also [here](https://www.numpyninja.com/post/mice-algorithm-to-impute-missing-values-in-a-dataset). However,  is it true to use this approach for imputation on validation and test sets?

Comment: @shadowtalker Not necessarily, keeping the output allows for a larger sample size and helps impute missing independent variables as well. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/422876/including-dependent-variables-in-multiple-imputation-model-when-they-have-missin and https://doi.org/10.1186/s12874-016-0281-5

Comment: How do you make out-of-sample predictions then?

Comment: @shadowtalker [The answer to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33500047/r-mice-machine-learning-re-use-imputation-scheme-from-train-to-test-set) suggests that for out-of-sample prediction we should set the ignore as FALSE, but I am not sure about it. Thanks.