# Impute additional dataset 2 based on initial dataset 1 - mice package

Tags: r, statistics, imputation, r-mice

I have a situation in which I have an initial dataset to which subsequent datasets will be added over time.  These future datasets will need to be imputed.

Is it possible with the mice package in R to add additional rows to an imputed dataset, and impute those additional rows with the same assumed distributions as the first dataset was imputed?  In this case I would not want the new data to skew the distributions from which imputed values were drawn?

```
data <- airquality
data[4:10, 3] <- rep(NA, 7)
data[1:5, 4] <- NA

data.1 <- data[1:140, ]
data.2 <- data[141:153, ]

library(mice)

tempData <- mice(data.1, m=5, maxit=50, meth='pmm', seed=500)
summary(tempData)

# Now impute data.2 drawing from data.1's distributions.
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39618648/impute-missing-data-while-forcing-correlation-coefficient-to-remain-the-same/39622066#39622066

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R - mice - machine learning: re-use imputation scheme from train to test set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33500047/r-mice-machine-learning-re-use-imputation-scheme-from-train-to-test-set)